# How to write unit test for play2 scala implicit import dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit, specs2

```
//DataBaseAdapterObject.scala
package services.db
object DataBaseAdapterObject{
  def findAllBlogItems() : List[String] = {
    ........
    ........
    List("One", "Two", "Three")
  }
}

//BaseService.scala
package services
import services.db._
object BaseService {
  implicit val db = DataBaseAdapterObject;
}


//BlogItemService.scala
package services
import services.BaseService._

object BlogItemService {
  def findAll() : List[String] = {
    db.findAllBlogItems()
  }
}
```

For above implementation I want to write unit test for the BlogItemService.findAll, The problem is because the db val is resolved by import I cannot mock the db object.
Does anybody know how to mock that implicit import db.

I know that the code can be written differently by implementing DI but I want to know if any work around for this case?

Application context -> play framework + specs2

Comment: In this way you cannot have different resources in test. The DB or connection should better be an implicit param of the functions, not imported.

Comment: Thanks cchantep, I wanted to be sure that there is no way to write test for this.

Comment: There is way, but not with a code designed like that

Comment: Ok, and thanks for the ans cchantep